# How to "listen" change of boolean value

Tags: android

I'm making an android app related to hardware, I have to listen to the boolean value tempIgnStat change.
I want these listeners to detect multiple changes.

For example (b1 is boolean1):
b1=false-->b1=true, then we do thing1.

I tried PropertyChangeEvent but couldn't succeed.
what should I do..?

Any technical advice or comments/suggestions on the best implementation would be hugely appreciated.

```
String getIgnitionStatus() {
    int ret;
    boolean[] tempIgnStat = new boolean[1];
    ret = mIvcpAPI.ivcp_pm_get_ignition_status(tempIgnStat);
   

    if(ret == MRM_ERROR.MRM_ERR_NO_ERROR) {

        return (tempIgnStat[0] ? "ON" : "OFF" );
    } else {

        return String.format("ERR - 0x%08X", ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try LiveData<Boolean> tempIgnStat with boolean you don't need to add any callbacks for the same.

Comment: @GevariaPurva 
Thank you for your suggestion,But i just want b1=false-->b1=true,  we do thing1, 
  Then b1=true-->b1=false, we do nothing. Can this method be used?

Comment: yes that will work and I will suggest it's the easiest one.  Just implement at your listener. 

MutableLiveData<Boolean> tempIgnStat;


tempIgnStat.postValue(true/false); //Add false/true logic here

tempIgnStat.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean newValue) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onChanged: "+newValue);//
   }
});